# "Not... neither... nor..." word order

Tags: word-order, negation, neither-nor

George Galloway is an outspoken MP with excellent rhetorical skills. I will take a part of his speech to convey the idea of my question.

[Video](http://www.tubechop.com/watch/898968)

> Iraq is neither strong, independent nor even a single country any more.

Would it be correct to rephrase the sentence above using this order "not/neither/nor" as follows:

> Iraq is not strong neither independent nor even a single country any more.

And so on, can I form sentences similar to it, for example:

> I am not mean neither greedy nor arrogant.

Would that be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. The order can either be

> I am not X nor Y nor Z.

Or it can be

> I am neither X nor Y nor Z.

Or even

> I am not X and neither am I Y or Z.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. 
And the form that George used is correct as well, right? 

Iraq is neither X, Y nor Z.

Comment: I'm not _sure_ it is not grammatical but I would not use it myself.

Comment: Some people will tell you that *neither* can only be used with two items, and of those some would object even to terdon's second example here. However it's long been used for more than two items, and terdon's second example can definitely have a good effective punch as can Galloway's, so I for one wouldn't be one to say it's not allowed. In cases where you could use "none of" or "none" rather than "neither", it's often a good idea to do so, but frankly Galloway's statement would be weaker if it was rewritten to that, so I wouldn't consider that a case.

Comment: @terdon @ Jon Hanna 
In his well-known testimony before the US senate, George Galloway's opening statement was as follows: Senator, I am not now nor have I ever been an oil trader and neither has anyone on my behalf. (Sic) 
He used this order: not, nor and neither 
So is it correct to say:
Iraq is not strong nor independent and neither is a single country anymore .. or .. I am not mean nor greedy and neither am I arrogant?

Comment: I find the sentence _I am not mean nor greedy and neither am I arrogant_ clumsy. However, Galloway's is not. I believe the difference lies in that the _neither_ in his case refers to a third person but I cannot tell you why. Perhaps @JonHanna can.

Comment: @BrightPolyglot: I think reading the not, nor, and neither in that sentence as forming a sequence of three is an error. It reads to me like a two-part sentence: "[I am not now nor have I ever been an oil trader] and [neither has anyone on my behalf]". Similarly, "I am not mean nor greedy and neither am I arrogant" would place arrogance in a different (possibly contrasting) category than meanness and greed. I would suggest that it seems awkward because -- at least in the absence of context -- this is a strange thing to do.

Comment: @terdon You said: "I find the sentence I am not mean nor greedy and neither am I arrogant clumsy. However, Galloway's is not" Because it refers to a third person, but you didn't comment on the other sentence, which is "Iraq is not strong nor independent and neither is it a single country anymore." It obviously refers to a 3rd person. Since you did not comment on it, does that mean that you approve of it?

Comment: @BrightPolyglot well, yes I do, for what my approval is worth. I think that Micah has a point. The form _not A nor B and neither C_ implies two groups. A and B on the one hand and C on the other. This is the case with Galloway's sentence with _free and independent_ in one group and _single country_ in another. It will seem strange if the grouping is counter intuitive and natural if the grouping is reasonable.

Comment: how about 
1-"I'm not X nor Y,Y,Z"?
2-"I'm not X or Y,Y,Z"?